# Unable to start activity befor dagger hilt injection

Tags: android, dependency-injection, fragment, dagger-hilt

I have some injections in viewModels (like room) without problem
Now i'm trying to inject into my fragment but the app crash.

Fragment:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ContactListFragment @Inject constructor(private val newContactDialog: NewContactDialog) :
    Fragment() {

}
```

Module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ContactModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideNewContactDialog(): NewContactDialog {
        return NewContactDialog()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContactListFragment(contactDialog: NewContactDialog): ContactListFragment {
        return ContactListFragment(contactDialog)
    }
}
```

part of the error

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.roomcontactlist/com.example.roomcontactlist.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in com.example.roomcontactlist:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #18 in com.example.roomcontactlist:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView

and the main activity xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navgraph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

line 18 is `app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navgraph"`

Comment: First of two things to note here is Make ``Application``` class Annotated with @HiltAndroidApp and then In Your Main Activity Add @AndroidEntryPoint.

Comment: yes, i have this. Also, i have some injections in the viewmodel working (room database)

Comment: You are using navigation architecture component, then why are you injecting Fragment? I think if you remove that it should work.

Comment: because im using to open my custom dialgo with newContactDialog.show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, "NewContactDialog"), not with navigation

Comment: Then you can @Inject your Dialog into Fragment. You do not need to inject fragment constructor. `@Inject lateinit var dialog: NewContactDialog`